# How to compile C# Webapplication without VS?

Tags: c#, web-applications, compiler-construction, compilation

Is it possible to publish a web application without visual studio ?

If i got all my file on a compiling server without visual studio, is it possible to compile my files with command promp or something like that ?

Comment: Compiling and publishing are two separate things. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: When you say web app, do you mean that the project is defined as a web app as opposed to a web site (in other words, that it uses a project file)?

Comment: I got a code generator, whoe generate my web site, and i generate a web site (without cs.proj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need ASP.NET Compilation Tool (Aspnet_compiler.exe)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: This is correct if the goal is to precompile the code-behinds. Whether that's the goal is a bit unclear, though. And, even so, it still uses `csc.exe` (for C# code).

Comment: I thought of Web application as of a project is compiled into a single assembly. I've used this kind in VS 2003 or VS 2005, then you have an assembly with a business logic and all that stuff you usually put in App_Code in web site. Then you just call aspnet_compiler.exe on the directory and get a distributable fully compiled output. 
But it was a long time ago and I can be wrong.

Comment: I don't think you're wrong (so I'm not sure why you were downvoted), but I do think the original question is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Yep, a bit more of details would definitely helped to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Build:

```
msbuild .\Project.sln
```

Publish:

```
msbuild .\Project.Web.csproj /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /t:MsDeployPublish /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=yourdomain.com;DeployIisAppPath="YourIISSiteName";username=YourAdminUser;password=YourAdminPassword
```

(msbuild.exe is located in your .NET framework location. i.e.  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319)

Comment: Will this work equally well for web apps and web sites (the two project types, I mean).